# Getting local variable names defined inside a method from outside the method

Tags: ruby, scope, metaprogramming

Is it possible in Ruby to get all the local variables names defined inside a method from outside the method using metaprogramming?

```
def foo
  var = 100
  arr = [1,2]
end
```

Something like *foo.local_variables*.

I only need to retrieve the variable names, not their values.

**Why I'm trying to find those variable names**: I have a class where I want to dynamically generate setters for all instance variables initialized in "#initialize".

In order to do that, inside "initialize", I am using something like `instance_variables.each do |inst_var_name| define_singleton_method(...) do ...`

This works: each instanced object gets its setters as singleton methods. However, I was looking for a solution where I could read the instance variables names from outside the "initialize" method, in order to be able to use "#define_method" for them, and create regular methods and not singleton methods.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Unlike instance variables, which exist as long as the object exists, local variables don't exist until the method is called and cease to exist as soon as the method returns. There is no "inside the method" and "outside the method"; there is only "while the method is being executed" and "while the method is not being executed." What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If it's possible, how much meta data should ruby keep at runtime? how much memory will they occupy? It's just not feasible.

Comment: @Jordan I disagree. I am not trying to get the value of local variables, just their name. As it is possible to get the source code of a method, I was wondering if there was also some method to get the names of just the local variables defined (or attempted to be defined) in a method... makes sense?

Comment: While the answer to your question is "no", If you add the line `p local_variables` to `foo`, executing `foo` will cause `[:var, :arr]` to be displayed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that's not a serious comment, is it :)

Comment: Try it! `def foo; p local_variables; var = 100; arr = [1,2]; end; foo #=> [:var, :arr]`.

Comment: I thought you were joking because you are just telling me to print the local variables from inside a method. Of course I know I can do this! But I need to do that from outside the method...

Comment: I made it clear that it didn't answer your question, but since you referred to  `local_variables_get` in your question I didn't know you were aware of the method `local_variables`.

Comment: I understand where the confusion came from. I actually meant to type *local_variables* in the question. Updating it. Thanks.

Comment: @jj_ Whether or not you agree is immaterial. Yes, that information exists in the source code, and if you want you can use one of the Ruby parsing gems to parse the source code and then walk the AST to find all local variable declarations. But that information does not exist in the Ruby runtime in any form that we, from outside the method, have or can gain access to.

Comment: ...although the parsing approach will fail you as well in the case of e.g. `define_method` or `instance_eval("def ...")`. You still haven't told us what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Further to @Jordan's points, because Ruby is a dynamic language, a given method may have one set of local variables at one point in time and another set at some other time.

Comment: @Jordan the problem I am trying to solve is the following: I want to dynamically generate setters for all instance variables initialized in "#initialize". To do that, Inside "initialize", I am using something like `instance_variables.each do |inst_var_name| define_singleton_method(...) ...`. This works and each instanced object gets its setters as singleton methods. However, I was looking for a solution where I could read the instance variables names from outside the "initialize" method, so to be able to use "#define_method" for them, and create regular methods and not singleton methods.

Comment: That's an interesting problem. I suggest posting that question, along with the code you have so far. You might get some clever solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (re)-parse the method and inspect the S-EXPR tree. See below for a proof of concept. You can get hold of the file where the method is defined using `Method#source_location` and then read that file. There is surely room for improvement to my code but should get you started. It is a fully functional piece of code and only requires the ruby parser gem (https://github.com/whitequark/parser).

```
require 'parser/current'
node = Parser::CurrentRuby.parse(DATA.read) # DATA is everything that comes after __END__

def find_definition(node, name)
  return node if definition_node?(node, name)
  if node.respond_to?(:children)
    node.children.find do |child|
      find_definition(child, name)
    end
  end
end

def definition_node?(node, name)
  return false if !node.respond_to?(:type)
  node.type == :def && node.children.first == name
end

def collect_lvasgn(node)
  result = []
  return result if !node.respond_to?(:children)

  node.children.each do |child|
    if child.respond_to?(:type) && child.type == :lvasgn
      result << child.children.first
    else
      result += collect_lvasgn(child)
    end
  end

  result
end

definition = find_definition(node, :foo)
puts collect_lvasgn(definition)

__END__

def foo
  var = 100
  arr = [1,2]
  if something
    this = 3 * var
  end
end

def bar
  var = 200
  arr = [3, 4]
end
```

Do you mind telling us WHY you want to find the variables?

Comment: Hi, I added some related info to the question, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Not sure i fully understand your requirements. But it sounds like a hackish way of doing something. If it is that complicated to do, then its probably not very idiomatic (though you can do it). Also my way probably has shortcomings when it comes to dynamically created stuff.

Comment: Yes I know it feels too hackish, but it's one of those times where you face the occasion of learning something new, so you keep pushing it! :) the actual problem is not really that  important anymore.. and I really hope there is another approach to it. I'll probably post a question just for discussing that.

Answer (score 0):

These variables only exist briefly as Jordan points out, they exist only as long as the method is actively executing and are discarded immediately after.

If you want to instrument these you need to do it inside the method. The method itself does not allow this sort of reflection.

Comment: Please look at my comment in reply to @Jordan under my question.

Comment: If you're feeling extremely brave you might want to try dumping the internal Ruby P-code and parse that, but I think what you're asking for is not supported at all by regular Ruby.

Comment: Actually, in any halfway decent compiler (e.g. Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby), the local variables in this example will be optimized away completely (as will the entire first line).

Comment: @JörgWMittag A good point, since these are actually useless and can safely be discarded.